# Should I be worried about Wmissing-field-initializers and aggregate initialization in C++17?

Tags: c++, c++17, aggregate-initialization

I compiled some code with GCC with `-Wall` and `-Wextra` enabled. This code produces a warning:

```
struct A { A(int) {} };
struct B {};

struct C : A, B {};

int main() {
    (void) C{1};
}
```

> ```
> main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
> main.cpp:11:15: warning: missing initializer for member 'C::<anonymous>' [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
>      (void) C{1};
>                ^
> ```

Should I be worried about that? Is this a bug in GCC for outputting this warning? It seems I have no field to initialize, and no missing parameters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C++17 allows you to perform aggregate initialization on classes with base classes. Each base class is effectively considered a member (they come before the direct members of the class). So to aggregate initialization, `C` has two "members": `C::A` and `C::B`.

You only initialized one.

Oh sure, `B` doesn't actually have anything to initialize. But to `-Wall`, it's no different from this:

```
struct C
{
  A a;
  B b;
};

(void) C{1};
```

This would give a warning too. You would silence it in either case by providing an explicit initializer for `B`: `(void)C{1, {}};`.

But as far as the standard is concerned, this is perfectly valid code. `B` will be value initialized. In either case.

Comment: Oh well... I'm dealing with generic code there, so I would be hard to add the empty parameters :(

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Would it possibly help you to know the expected number of initializers? These can be counted using SFINAE.